# Analog of COM programming in Linux/UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, com, components

The Component Object Model (COM) is (or was...) the way in Windows to provide language-neutral software components.

Is there any programming model in Linux/UNIX with the same philosophy of code reuse through binary components?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Sun RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) was supposed to be that. Then there was [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba). Then [GNOME Bonobo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonobo_(component_model)) and [KDE DCOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCOP). Now it looks like [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) is latest fashion.

Comment: Yes, seems DBUS is the way to go.

Thankz.

Comment: Ah! What about XPCOM? It's too much restricted to programming for Mozilla projects? Or it's COM-like?

Comment: About XPCOM, it is not that easy to use apart from Mozilla. Also, don't forget Uno, the counerpart for OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Comment: DBUS is not a component system. It just provides IPC (inter-process communication) and activation (doing IPC with a process that is not started yet). It does not support in-process components (like loadable libraries or ActiveX controls), nor does it have many standardized interfaces (a la "embeddable control", "file viewer for file type XY",  IDispatch, persistant storage, OLE, ... like you have in COM). Basically, nowadays (2012) all of this is replaced by one-off DBUS interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, [DBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) is currently in the process of becoming the de-facto higher-level standard.

Answer (score 2):

The Evolution email client as part of GNOME uses CORBA. It uses ORBit which is a lightweight CORBA ORB.

http://projects.gnome.org/ORBit2/