# Is there an equivalent to COM on *nix systems ? If not, what was the *nix approach to re-usability?

Tags: linux, unix, architecture, com

I have an understanding of windows COM and the ideas behind it.  I am trying to understand if *nix systems even have an equivalent or why they don't?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Unix model is built around the idea of lightweight processes that communicate with each other, through sockets, pipes, signals, and command lines.  Historically, Unix didn't have threads (the POSIX thread model is only about 10 years old IIRC), but processes on Unix have always been much cheaper than on Windows, so it was more performant to factor functionality into separate executables than to allow a single program to grow large and monolithic.

In COM, you define binary interfaces that allow shared-memory communication.  COM is tied to an *object-oriented* paradigm.  In the classic Unix model, you define stream-oriented interfaces that allow communication over pipes, without shared memory.  Conceptually, this is much closer to a *functional* programming paradigm.

The Unix model encourages making small programs that can be easily coupled together by a lightweight "shell", while the COM model encourages making large programs that expose "components" that can be reused by other large programs.  It's really an apples-and-oranges comparison, since both models provide benefits and drawbacks for different scenarios.

Of course, modern Unix systems can have COM-like facilities.  Mozilla has XPCOM, a cross-platform framework built on the same principles as COM.  GNOME for a long time used Bonobo, which is conceptually very similar to Microsoft OLE, which was the forerunner to COM.  But recent versions of GNOME have been shifting away from Bonobo in favor of D-Bus, which is more of an event/messaging pattern.

Comment: +1. Just put KDE's KParts and DCOP in there, and you have pretty much all there is to know. (Small nitpick: shell programming is actually more like dataflow programming than functional programming.)

Comment: "the POSIX thread model is only about 10 years old IIRC" 15 years old, actually... as IEEE Std 1003.1c-1995.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: True enough.  But I've always considered dataflow programming and functional programming to be pretty closely related.  COM's component-centric model, on the other hand, seems like the opposite end of the spectrum, which was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Thanks for the reference.  I think what I was remembering was the Native POSIX Threading Library for Linux 2.6, which was the first stable Linux threading implementation that actually performed reasonably well.  It came out in 2003.

Comment: The other tech you're missing is SUN RPC, which was fairly popular for a while.

Comment: COM was created with mainly-graphical system (Windows) in mind — drag-and-drop, document embedding, 3rd-party video decoders, etc. To enable this stuff, you really need immutable interfaces, language-agnostic data layouts and `AddRef/Release` pair. COM has driven OOP's ideas of polymorphism and encapsulation to the logical/absurd end (not sure what word to pick: but there is really tons of DI and IoC stuff there), with all those factories and proxies and monikers and whatnot... And GUI was never a big priority on Linux until the very recent time. So on Linux, COM is being reinvented now.

Comment: It is quite presumptuous to claim, that huge processes are avoidable. How many processes and pipes are used to compose for example googles chrome browser on unix? ;) It is kind of nonsensical to think this lots of small processes paradigm covers the whole space of programs written. Also, I think one major reason why *nix does not have something like COM is, that shared libraries load more slowly compared to DLLs (lots of relocation operations). At least it used to be like that a few years back when I last checked.

Comment: @BitTickler, I've come to the conclusion lacking COM has irreparably harmed software on Linux based platforms. The entire ecosystem does one thing very well, making Unix clones... that's it. Just like Unix was then, it promotes centralization, .. which then results in fragmentation or oppression from a monopoly. which is why distributions are necessary... why one giant conglomerate must provide so many services, It doesn't excel at providing a general purpose OS, which promotes a vibrant open source ecosystem, or even an ecosystem which promotes many smaller players.

Comment: @BitTickler, for all the good talk about freedom, Linux only provides the freedom to the Googles of the world, it's time for a new system. ... or Windows, until a new system is ready.

Answer (score 37):

The closest would probably be [D-Bus](http://DBus.FreeDesktop.Org/). D-Bus is a lightweight IPC protocol and Object Request Broker (ORB) very similar to COM and heavily inspired by both COM and D-Bus's predecessors [DCOP](http://Developer.KDE.Org/documentation/other/dcop.html) (KDE) and [CORBA](https://web.archive.org/web/20090803090613/http://library.gnome.org:80/devel/platform-overview/stable/bonobo-corba.html.en) (GNOME) as well as [Netlink](http://IETF.Org/rfc/rfc3549) (Linux Kernel).

Before D-Bus, both major Unix desktop environments had their own component models and desktop busses. GNOME had Bonobo which was based on CORBA and KDE had KParts which was based on DCOP. And the Linux Kernel has Netlink which is a communication protocol between kernel and userspace which is used for example by the `iproute2` tool whenever you configure a networking interface.

The kernel developers constantly got requests to release Netlink as a separate part for communication between userspace programs, however they feared that this would lead to feature bloat and maintenance problems. In the end, under the umbrella of the Free Desktop organization whose goal it is to create cros-desktop standards, both the KDE and GNOME developers got together to develop an IPC messaging system based on the best parts of DCOP and Netlink, and the result was D-Bus.

In current versions of both GNOME and KDE, D-Bus has completely replaced CORBA and DCOP, thus making it possible to run GNOME applications in KDE and vice-versa with much higher fidelity. D-Bus has also been picked up by many other desktop environments and applications, not only on Linux but other Unix systems, as well as OSX and even Windows.

An alternative that should at least be mentioned is Mozilla's [XPCOM](https://Developer.Mozilla.Org/en/XPCOM/), which is a cross-platform object model heavily inspired by CORBA and COM. (In fact, XPCOM is an acronym for Cross-Platform Component Object Model.) It uses an IDL very similar to CORBA called XPIDL. However, as far as I know, nobody actually uses XPCOM, it is recognized both by critics as well as developers of Firefox and other Mozilla applications as one major source of bloat, and the Mozila developers are in fact actively working on reducing the usage of XPCOM especially *inside* components like Gecko.

However, as @Daniel Pryden points out, there's a lot of stuff *already* in Unix that should be preferred over D-Bus in cases where tight integration with a desktop is not needed. I am talking about stuff like pipes, named pipes and sockets.

Comment: Excellent answer. Why would the top developers of GNOME and KDE invest their time into D-Bus? They could just say: D-Bus is not needed let us all just use "stuff" like pipes, named pipes and sockets. But they did not.

Comment: Interprocess communication is not the thing COM is most used for.  Perhaps you were thinking of ActiveX.

Answer (score 4):

Closest would probably be [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA)