# Can we use jacob.jar in linux env?

Tags: java, jacob

I am working with Jacob jar for some of the operation involves bridging to COM objects. In windows I have loaded Jacob.dll explicitly, I have done a little search over internet to find the supported .so file for Linux, but I did not found the file.

Could any one help me with this question, if it is possible to use Jacob jar support in unix/Linux operating system or not?

Comment: Aren't COM objects a Windows specific thing? If so, why do you need it on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to use jacob on linux for? Jacob is a Java-COM bridge. COM stands for 'Component Object Model' and is a proprietary binary-interface standard for software components introduced by Microsoft in 1993. There is no COM on linux. Some discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063321/is-there-an-equivalent-to-com-on-nix-systems-if-not-what-was-the-nix-approa).
You maybe want to access an *.so file which can be done using [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) which is available for linux and lots of other [platforms](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native)...

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. understood

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like JACOB would support Linux, although there were [some discussions](https://sourceforge.net/p/jacob-project/discussion/375945/thread/74506e7f/) on using Wine for that.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I understood