# How to use a windows COM+ object with .NET core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, com+

I have an .NET Core service that runs successfully on Windows and uses a third-part COM+ application we depend on via an Interop dll to use an API.
The client wants this service to run on Linux.
Is there any way to do this ?

Tried to run the .Net Core app on Linux and (obviously) got this error message : Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported

Comment: As COM is an interface technology by Microsoft I doubt that it is possible to run that on a UNIX system. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063321/is-there-an-equivalent-to-com-on-nix-systems-if-not-what-was-the-nix-approa

Comment: Unless the third party app runs on Linux this is a non-starter anyway.

Comment: Erik T. I cannot use COM equivalent for *nix. I must use COM because I depend on the third-part app.